# How to display CPU, Heap, Uptime, OS and other info on all SOLR nodes?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

[image: SOLR Cloud]

I have a SOLR Cloud configured and working with 3 nodes. This is used to support a Sitecore 10 installation, although this is probably not relevant to the question.

For some reason, as you can see from the picture above, some information (such as Operating System, Java version, Uptime, Heap) is displayed only on `solr1`, while the other nodes are not showing those info.

Is there a way to make this information available for all nodes? I have searched in the documentation and on the Internet without being able to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to individual server IP's and on the Dashboard section check the settings if you are able to see these properties there. Like heap size, java memory.

One property is Xmx and Xms. If these are visible in first node and not on other nodes, means you have not configured solr on all the servers with same properties.

In that case, you have to update the settings for the solr on all the servers and restart the solr service.